# Overloading blocks with dust.js for nested templates

Tags: dust.js

I have a layout called `layouts/master.dust`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{+title /}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>This is the master header</h3>
    
    {+body /}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I then have a template called `index.dust`:

```
{>"layouts/master" /}

{<body}
    <h1>{@pre type="content" key="greeting"/}</h1>
{/body}
```

Predictably, that outputs

> This is the master header
>
> Hello, Alex!

(when supplied with the relevant json)

My issue is, I'm creating another "nested" or "child" template: `layouts/admin.dust` that looks like:

```
{>"layouts/master" /}

<h4>This is an admin header</h4>

{+body /}
```

and a template `adminIndex.dust` that uses `layouts/admin/dust` like this:

```
{>"layouts/admin" /}

{<body}
    <p>This is some stuff for admin</p>
{/body}
```

My problem, is the output is:

> This is the master header
> This is some stuff for admin
>
> This is an admin header
>
> This is some stuff for admin

So, my `{+body}` block is being called twice, and not overridden by my nested template

Is there a way to do that?

**Edit**

As per my comment, a more 'realistic' example of `admin.dust` would be:

```
{>"layouts/master" /}

<h4>This is an admin header</h4>

<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
<strong>left nav</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Link one</li>
    <li>Link two</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="float: right">
    {+ body /}
</div>
```

Where by in templates that use the `admin` layout, their `body` is in a div floated right (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `{+body}` block is being overridden by your `{<body}` inline partial in your `adminIndex.dust` template. The contents of an inline partial (in your case `<p>This is some stuff for admin</p>`) will be inserted wherever a block is found in your template. If you are hoping to have the master header be replaced by the admin header, you would need your templates to look like this:

`layouts/master.dust`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{+title /}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    {+header}<h3>This is the master header</h3>{/header}

    {+body /}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`layouts/admin.dust`

```
{>"layouts/master" /}

{+header}<h4>This is an admin header</h4>{/header}
```

`adminIndex.dust` requires no change.

Note: I have added a `{+header}` block to `layouts/master.dust` with a default value, and added a `{header}` inline partial and removed the `{+body}` block from `layouts/admin.dust`. This will output:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>This is the admin header</h3>


        <p>This is some stuff for admin</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THanks for your answer.. in reality, admin.dust would contain a 2 column layout, left being a "nav" area, right being the "body" or content... is there a way of specifying in admin.dust where the body should be rendered?

Comment: I have edited my admin.dust template to reflect the above comment

Comment: Can you add what you expect the output to be (including HTML) for admin and non-admin pages?

Comment: In your code you wrote `{/haeder}` instead of `{/header}`. Stackoverflow requires 6 chars to change for edit. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯